# Calculating a batting average, want to remove leading 0 in front of decimal point

Tags: php, number-formatting

I know its gotta be easy, but instead of returning `0.333`, I'd like to return just the value of `.333`.

I've sourced different functions but can't seem to locate the one I need precisely.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`ltrim()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ltrim.php) in PHP:

```
ltrim((string) 0.333000, "0"); // ".333"
```

Note, this gives you as a string output.

Comment: There is no need to cast it to a string. `ltrim(0.333, '0');` should suffice.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte I know, just for safety.

Comment: Safety? If you would have said, it's for documentation ok, but safety? How is that more or less safe? And where do you declare strict?

Comment: @hakre Er... LoL. Sorry... I take back my words... 

Comment: Well, there can be situations where doing a cast actually make code more fail-safe. In this case it is not b/c PHP has that parameter in string context, that means PHP itself will turn the parameter into a string. This works especially well with floats and integers and PHP will do that for you (and very similar to the cast, so this is really superfluous) :-)